# How to write test case in Jasmine for the below methods

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

Could you please let us know how to write jasmine test case for the below methods in angular

Controller class methods:

```
hasProviderOther() {
  return this.isProviderOther;
}

onProviderSelected(selected: SelectionItem): void {
  this.selectedProvider = selected;
  this.scheme.name = this.selectedProvider.name;
  this.scheme.origoId = this.selectedProvider.id;
  if (this.selectedProvider.name == "Other...") {
    this.isProviderOther = true;
  } else {
    this.isProviderOther = false;
    this.scheme.other = "";
  }
}
```

Comment: What version are you using? Angular v1.x.x or Angular v2.x.x+?

Comment: Angular v1.5.11